# Large square brackets with text in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

How may I draw large square brackets below a set of nodes in tikzpicture with text? More specifically, I currently have the following code/output:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
    \centering
    \tikzstyle{mynode} = [circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.1cm, text centered]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
             [node distance=1.2cm]
            \node (1) [mynode]  {};
            \node (2) [mynode, right of=1]  {};
            \node (3) [mynode, right of=2] {};
            \node (4) [mynode, right of=3] {};
            \node (5) [mynode, right of=4] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:network}
\end{figure}
```

Which produces:

[image]

I would like to achieve something that looks like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be drawn by usual commands of TikZ.
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.8mm]
\def\a{.4}
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4}
\fill (\i,0) circle(2pt);

\draw[yshift=-3 mm] (0,0)--++(-90:\a)
--++(0:2) node[midway,above]{some text}--++(90:\a);

\draw[yshift=-3 mm] (1,-\a-.2)--++(-90:\a)
--++(0:2) node[midway,above]{some text}--++(90:\a);

\draw[yshift=-3 mm] (2,-2*\a-.4)--++(-90:\a)
--++(0:2) node[midway,above]{some text}--++(90:\a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```