# Adjacent large square brackets with text in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, brackets, text

Call me thick but, how do you tweak the code in the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498759/large-square-brackets-with-text-in-tikzpicture/528477#528477) so that brackets are adjacent, e.g., one starts at, say, point (0,0) and ends at point (2,0) and the next one goes from (2.5, 0) to (3.5, 0), etc., and so all are at the same level and not overlapping? I've been trying for hours on end to no avail!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the modified code to do as requestd:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.8mm]
\def\a{.4}
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
\fill (\i,0) circle(2pt);

\draw[yshift=-3 mm, red] (0,0)--++(-90:\a)
--++(0:2) node[midway,above]{some text}--++(90:\a);

\draw[yshift=-3 mm, blue] (2.5,0)--++(-90:\a)
--++(0:2) node[midway,above]{some text}--++(90:\a);

\draw[yshift=-3 mm, orange] (5,0)--++(-90:\a)
--++(0:2) node[midway,above]{some text}--++(90:\a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you as well! This is closer to the original code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498759/large-square-brackets-with-text-in-tikzpicture/528477#528477)

Answer (score 1):

No idea if I interpret your question in the right way, but maybe this is what you want. You can define a node style for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[brnode/.style={inner sep=4pt,path picture={
\draw[line width=2pt] 
    ([xshift=1pt,yshift=-1pt]path picture bounding box.north west)
    |- ([xshift=-1pt,yshift=1pt]path picture bounding box.south east)
    -- ([xshift=-1pt,yshift=-1pt]path picture bounding box.north east);}},
    font=\sffamily]
 \path[nodes={brnode,text depth=0.25ex},node distance=1em] 
    node (a) {pft}
    node[base right=of a] (b) {blub}
    node[base right=of b] (c) {hibernate};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's it!