# Explain polar coordinate syntax for rectangular path construction?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the manual for pgf 3.1.5 the following example is given for rectangular path construction:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
\draw (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\draw (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (-1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, the following 'polar looking' syntax was used in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498759/large-square-brackets-with-text-in-tikzpicture) by @Black Mild:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.8mm]
\def\a{.4}
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4}
\fill (\i,0) circle(2pt);

\draw[yshift=-3 mm] (0,0)--++(-90:\a)
--++(0:2) node[midway,above]{some text}--++(90:\a);

\draw[yshift=-3 mm] (1,-\a-.2)--++(-90:\a)
--++(0:2) node[midway,above]{some text}--++(90:\a);

\draw[yshift=-3 mm] (2,-2*\a-.4)--++(-90:\a)
--++(0:2) node[midway,above]{some text}--++(90:\a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried searching the pgf manual but couldn't find any documentation for this.  Any suggestion where to look?

Comment: Black mild uses at the same time the **relative coordinate** `++` and the **polar coordinates** `(-90:\a)` *(note `:` and not the `,`)*.

Comment: Polar coordinates are explained in section 13.2.1 *Canvas, XYZ, and Polar coordinate systems*, relative coordinates are explained in 13.4.1.